# Cannot get closest number input field value

Tags: jquery

I keep getting undefined as a result when trying to get the value of the closest input field to a button.

I have tried this:

```
$('button.add_to_cart_button.button.ajax_add_to_cart').on('click', function() {
        var v = $(this).closest('div.quantity').find("input[name='quantity']").val();
        console.log(v);
});
```

And this:

```
$('button.add_to_cart_button.button.ajax_add_to_cart').on('click', function() {
       var v = $(this).closest( '.input-text.qty' ).val();
       console.log(v);
});
```

But as mentioned I just get 'undefined' back.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="quantity">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5dce7f0dc2a65">Some label</label>
<input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
</div>
<button type="submit" data-product_id="123" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button button ajax_add_to_cart">Buy</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$(this).prev('div.quantity')`, since `.quantity` is not a parent of your button, but a sibling.

Your code would work if your button was *inside* the `.quantity`.

**Demo**

```js
$('button.add_to_cart_button.button.ajax_add_to_cart').on('click', function() {
  var v = $(this).prev('div.quantity').find("input[name='quantity']").val();
  console.log(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5dce7f0dc2a65">Some label</label>
  <input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
</div>
<button type="submit" data-product_id="123" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button button ajax_add_to_cart">Buy</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your html markup like this:

```
<div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5dce7f0dc2a65">Some label</label>
    <input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">

    <button type="submit" data-product_id="123" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button button ajax_add_to_cart">Buy</button>
</div>
```

or use `prev()` jQuery function like this:

```
$('button.add_to_cart_button.button.ajax_add_to_cart').on('click', function() {
    var v = $(this).prev().find("input[name='quantity']").val();;
    console.log(v);
});
```